# Draggable scrolling. How to scroll while dragging?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, drag-and-drop, air, scroll

When I was starting to drag any element, mouse wheel scrolling is turned off, how to scroll while dragging?

I'm newbie here, so I can't insert a picture, here's a link https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tp69.gif

Comment: any success have you got?

Answer (score 0):

Hm... I would say it is because the scrolling is caught by the dragged element, as it is on top of the VGroup. So - I guess the solution would be to listen to scrolling event in the dragged element and send that to the VGroup / something that will handle the drag'n'scrolling of the VGroup.

Also - I am not sure, but when you are dragging, the VGroup might no more be specified as the dragged element's parent - so, just add a *realParent* reference or whatever so you can always access it.